# How many questions are asked per minute on MathStack-exchange

Tags: discussion, statistics

I was just curious of the average rate of questions being posted on Math-Stack exchange eg. 1 question per 30 seconds.

Does the site have any graphs that show this? Social-educational scientists are probably interested in monthly and annual instead.

Also, is there a map of which countries the posts originate?

On first search I found

[Featured Questions per time](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16983/featured-questions-per-time)

which includes monthly. So I guess I could divide to get the number. But there is nothing like raw data.

Thank you

Comment: Nice question, but do we really need to know the answer?

Answer (score 12):

You can get some real-time data using [API method /info](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=math&filter=!w-)08bs04y19S*F-w0). As of now:

```
"new_active_users": 10,
"total_users": 154488,
"badges_per_minute": 0.17,
"total_badges": 419856,
"total_votes": 2338422,
"total_comments": 1874084,
"answers_per_minute": 0.22,
"questions_per_minute": 0.15,
"total_answers": 532934,
"total_accepted": 198520,
"total_unanswered": 74245,
"total_questions": 363190
```

The [documentation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info) does not state the time interval used for "per minute" computation,  but it says that the query should not be invoked more than once per hour, and the number 10 of new users is consistent with this interval being 1 hour.  So, it seems that 0.15 questions per minute were asked in the past hour. It's relatively quiet due to a weekend (long weekend in the USA).

For a larger interval of time, see [Site List](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), according to which 609 questions per day were asked on average over the last two weeks. This is 0.42 questions/minute.

#### Distribution by country

[Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/math.stackexchange.com) offers some data of this kind. It does not differentiate by the  kind of activity (posting questions, answers, or just reading). The geographic distribution of visitors over the last 30 days  is as follows:

```
1. USA 45.49%
2. India 9.14%
3. UK 7.17%
4. Canada 6.09%
5. Australia 2.50%
6. Germany 2.18%
7. Philippines 1.32% 
8. Pakistan 1.23%
```

(other countries <1% each)